# How does input onChange work in react, with state?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

So when I'm trying to log the value of the input every `onChange` event fires, it gives a weird 1 event delay, As 'some text' would be the default value on the input, say when I remove 't' from 'some text' by pressing backspace/delete it logs 'some text' first instead of 'some tex' then when the 2nd `onChange` (keystroke) fires that's the time I get the expected log (see photo below). Is there something that I'm missing, a gap on my understanding maybe?

So basically what's happening is, when you do some key stoke it's just logging any default value first then you get the expected log after pressing more keystroke in "1-event-callback-delayed" manner. weird eh? how would I get rid of the delay? help.

```
const TestComponent = () => {

  const [val, setVal] = React.useState('some text');
  const handleOnchange = React.useCallback((event: TypeEvent) => {
    setVal(event.target.value);
    console.log(val);
  }, [val]);

  return (
    <>
      <input type='text' value={val} onChange={handleOnchange} />
    </>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: `setVal` queues up a change to the state but you won't see the variable `val` change until the next render of your component. You're logging the current value before the changes are applied and the component re-rendered.

Comment: hmmm how do i make sure im logging the updated `val`?

Comment: if you `console.log(val)` in your function (outside of useEffect) then you'll be seeing the correct value in that moment for that particular render. Remember that `setVal` is going to cause a re-render so you'll get a new log of that value.

Answer (score 2):

Console the value `e.target.value` which is been set to the state,

inside the handler without `useCallback` would be fine.

```js
const App = () => {
const [val, setVal] = React.useState('some text');
const handleOnchange = e => {
  console.log(e.target.value)
  setVal(e.target.value)
}
return (
  <div className="App">
    <input type='text' value={val} onChange={handleOnchange} />
  </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

---

Update: demo with `useCallback`

```js
const App = () => {
const [val, setVal] = React.useState('some text');
const handleOnchange = React.useCallback(e => {
  console.log(e.target.value);
  setVal(e.target.value);
}, [val]);
return (
  <div className="App">
    <input type='text' value={val} onChange={handleOnchange} />
  </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: sorry useCallback is a requirement bud

Comment: actually, the results are the same with or without the `useCallback` hook delay still there

Comment: this is fine, but I need `useCallback`

Comment: to prevent unnecessary re-renders

Comment: @swoopy You can check the updated demo, I didn't see any problems.

Comment: hmmm that's kinda weird, `val` is not being updated inside the handleOnchange. Can you explain why?

Comment: @swoopy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately